# find discretization steps

Tags: matlab, math

I have data files F_j, each containing a list of numbers with an unknown number of decimal places. Each file contains discretized measurements of some continuous variable and
I want to find the discretization step d_j for file F_j

A solution I could come up with: for each F_j,

- find the number (n_j) of decimal places;
- multiply each number in F_j  with 10^{n_j} to obtain integers;
- find the greatest common divisor of the entire list.

I'm looking for an elegant way to find n_j with Matlab.

Also, finding the gcd of a long list of integers seems hard — do you have any better idea?

Comment: Is there only one number per file?  Or are all the numbers in the file going to be the same length, after the decimal point?

Comment: discretization is not the same as number of decimal places!

Answer (score 0):

Finding the gcd of a long list of numbers isn't *too* hard. You can do it in time linear in the size of the list. If you get lucky, you can do it in time a lot less than linear. Essentially this is because:

```
gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(gcd(a,b),c)
```

and if either `a=1` or `b=1` then `gcd(a,b)=1` regardless of the size of the other number.

So if you have a list of numbers `xs` you can do

```
g = xs(1);

for i = 2:length(xs)
  g = gcd(x(i),g);
  if g == 1
    break
  end
end
```

The variable `g` will now store the gcd of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that I believe will help you get the GCD once you have the numbers you want to look at.

```
A = [15 30 20];
A_min = min(A);
GCD = 1;
for n = A_min:-1:1
    temp = A / n;
    if (max(mod(temp,1))==0)
        % yay GCD found
        GCD = n;
        break;
    end
end
```

The basic concept here is that the default GCD will always be 1 since every number is divisible by itself and `1` of course =).  The GCD also can't be greater than the smallest number in the list, thus I start with the smallest number and then decriment by 1.  This is assuming that you have already converted the numbers to a whole number form at this point.  Decimals will throw this off!

By using the modulus of 1 you are testing to see if the number is a whole number, if it isn't you will have a decmial remainder left which is greater than 0.  If you anticipate having to deal with negative you will have to tweak this test!

Other than that, the first time you find a number where the modulus of the list (mod 1) is all zeros you've found the GCD.

Enjoy!